# Pandas Python remove elements from list with condition

Tags: python, pandas, list

Suppose I have a the following list

```js
List = ['0000', '0010', '0020', '0030', '0040', '0050', '0060', '0070']
```

Using Pandas python I want to remove elements from list where the 2nd last numbers is odd. I have the following code but I get an error.

```js
for a in List:
    if [int(a[-2]) for a in List] % 2 != 0:
        List.remove(a)
```

> Expected Output `List = ['0000', '0020', '0040', '0060']`

Comment: _I have the following code but I get an error_ Saying "I got an error" isn't very useful. 
 **Show** us the error.

Comment: `li.remove(a)` What is `li`?  You haven't defined that variable.

Comment: Forgive me @JohnGordon it meant to say `List` but an answer has been supplied already. Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing the error was `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'` since you are trying to apply `%` to something between brackets!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing items from list while iterating, maybe that's the root of the problem, Try out a list comprehension

```
List = ['0000', '0010', '0020', '0030', '0040', '0050', '0060', '0070']

List = [x for x in List if not x[-2] in [str(z) for z in range(1,10,2)]]

print(List)
```

Comment: Can you you kindly help me understand ` [str(z) for z in range(1,10,2)]`?

Comment: That is a list comprehension to iterate over the range of 1 to 11 with step 2 and convert each iteratiom variable to str and compare

Comment: In the event that I need to change the condition from ``Odd` to a list of numbers for example `[6,7,8,9]` am I correct to write `[str(z) for z in range(6,8,1)]`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question `pandas`:

```
out = pd.Series(List).loc[lambda x : x.str[-2].astype(int)%2==0].tolist()
Out[94]: ['0000', '0020', '0040', '0060']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in List:
    if int(a[-2]) % 2 != 0:
        List.remove(a)
```

Comment: This actually has quadratic time complexity because `remove` has to search for the element before removing it.

Comment: Suggested alternative: `newlist = []; for a in List: if a[-2] in '13579': newlist.append(a)`.